# What is the advantage of using a pointer to an object as the value in std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

In the youtube clip [Trading at light speed: designing low latency systems in C++ - David Gross - Meeting C++ 2022](https://youtu.be/8uAW5FQtcvE?t=1316) The presented presents the following:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<InstrumentId, Instrument> mInstruments;
// Upsides: Contiguous memory, cheap lookup
// Downsides: Random memory access ("Linked list")

std::vector<Instrument> mInstruments;
std::unordered_map<InstrumentId, Instrument*> mInstruments;
// Upsides: Contiguous memory, cheap lookup
// Downsides: expensive resize which invalidates pointers
```

Why is this an improvement? Isn't there still a linked list, only now with pointers instead of full objects? So you still have random memory access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second design allows you to use `for(Instrument &i : mInstruments)` to loop over all the instruments in contiguously ordered memory.

Comment: Ah i see, but then the nodes of the linked lists are still allocated randomly. Wont this hurt locality of the Instrument data?

Comment: @blanNL only if you use the linked list. Not if you use the vector. When you want to loop over every instrument, you use the vector. And that is *probably* the most important section of code to speed up, because calculating *every* instrument obviously takes longer than calculating just a few...

Comment: of course, if you never loop over all the instruments, only look them up one-by-one, then there is no point in doing it this way.